# Cython: How to sum a memoryviewslice object efficiently?

Tags: performance, numpy, cython

Im trying to speed up a function, which calculates the sum of all elements [integer] to the right of each element in a matrix and checks if the sum is even. I tried to use cython (memory views), but I make everything worse. :D 
I guess, I do not understand the type definitions right, as I get for example "Pyx_PyInt_From_npy_long" in the html file for the line wm[i,j] = (gx[i:,j].sum())%2 , which I thought to be all npy_long.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

ctypedef np.int_t dtype_int

@cython.wraparound(False)  
@cython.boundscheck(False) 
def test_fun(np.ndarray[dtype_int,ndim=2]  gx_in, dtype_int n):
    # Declarations
    cdef dtype_int i,j  
    cdef dtype_int[:,:] gx
    cdef dtype_int[:] gx_slice
    gx = gx_in

    # Init Array
    wm_init = np.zeros((n,n), dtype = np.int)
    cdef dtype_int[:,:] wm = wm_init

    # Loop
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            gx_slice = gx[i:,j]
            wm[i,j] = np.sum(gx_slice)%2
    return wm
```

I used np.sum() instead of .sum() (which was faster), because a memoryviewslice-object apparently has no attribute 'sum'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to speed up the loop (insert explicit loop for sum). It worked for my case and I guess it has something to do with the slicing, although I'm not sure.

```
ctypedef np.int_t dtype_int
@cython.wraparound(False)  
@cython.boundscheck(False) 
def test_fun(np.ndarray[dtype_int,ndim=2]  gx_in, dtype_int n):
    # Declarations
    cdef dtype_int i,j,k, gx_sum    
    cdef dtype_int[:,:] gx
    cdef dtype_int[:] gx_slice
    gx = gx_in

    # Init Array
    wm_init = np.zeros((n,n), dtype = np.int)
    cdef dtype_int[:,:] wm = wm_init

    # Loop
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            gx_sum = 0
            for k in range(i,n):
                gx_sum += gx[k,j]

            wm[i,j] = gx_sum%2
    return wm
```

Comment: It would be even faster if you iterated over a pointer to the memory block rather than using slicing. But yeah, you definitely *don't* want to call numpy functions in a tight loop, that will not give you any performance benefit over doing the same thing in cython.